# codeblocks removing autocomplete

Tags: c++, settings, codeblocks

Can someone help me figure out how to remove the darn prediction text in codeblocks?

Picture below, thanks

[image: the text box that makes my life slightly more annoying]

edit: sorry if I'm doing this wrong, first time on the site <3 all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto `Settings-> Editor-> Editor Settings` tab.
Uncheck code completion.